# GitHub action workflow not triggering

Tags: github-actions

I have created a new YAML file and that flow not triggering. Whereas I have other workflows that are working as expected.

I want to assign a label on the project card moved from to-do to in progress.

Not Working flow:

```yaml
name: Update Label on Project Card Move
on:
  project_card:
    types: [moved]
      
jobs:
  update_label:
    if: ${{ github.event.project_card.column_id == '192285912' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      issues: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            // this gets the number at the end of the content URL, which should be the issue/PR number
            const issue_num = context.payload.project_card.content_url.split('/').pop()
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              issue_number: issue_num,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              name: ["in progress"]
            })
```

Comment: Is your workflow in the default branch?

Comment: workflow created on main branch

Comment: Ok, is main your default branch? Everything looks correct from my end, you may want to check the notes section from the `project_card` event trigger https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#project_card

Comment: yes. main is default branch

Comment: Based on `project_card` note: `This event only occurs for projects (classic).`, you can check whether your project is classic or not.

Comment: Does your `github.event.project_card.column_id` has a correct value? Maybe, you need a different ID in this case

Comment: Yes..The project is classic and have correct column I’d

Comment: This event only occurs for projects owned by the workflow's repository, not for organization-owned or user-owned projects or for projects owned by another repository. What is this mean ?  Do I need to create/link a project on repo ? But I did not see an option to link classic project.  I link the repo to project not project to repo